# Query NetAdapter Wi-Fi aggressiveness on all computers

Tags: powershell, networking

`$Machines = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com' | Select-Object Name`

`$result = foreach ($Machine in $Machines) { if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Machine -Count 1 -Quiet) { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machine -ScriptBlock { Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi*" -DisplayName "Roaming Aggressiveness" | Select-Object Name,DisplayName, DisplayValue,PSComputerName } } else { Write-Warning "Computer '$Machine' does not respond" } }`

## output on the screen

`$result`

Comment: All the results i'm getting are 
WARNING: Computer '@{Name=LN-T48-XXXX}' does not respond

Comment: Change `Select-Object Name` into `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`, so you `$Machines` variable will become an string array of computer names. Now, it is an array of **objects** with just one property called 'Name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you are collecting **objects** in variable `$Machines`, where you are expecting just strings.

Try

```
$Machines = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
# or shorter:
# $Machines = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com').Name
$result = foreach ($Machine in $Machines) { 
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Machine -Count 1 -Quiet) { 
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machine -ScriptBlock { 
            Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi*" -DisplayName "Roaming Aggressiveness" | 
            Select-Object Name, DisplayName, DisplayValue, PSComputerName 
        }
    } 
    else { 
        Write-Warning "Computer '$Machine' does not respond" 
    }
} 

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\WiFiAgressiveness.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't letting me edit your original question to format the text so it's easier to read.

If your code is correct, you cannot put the Results of a `foreach` into a variable like `$result`.

I would suggest you output the outcome of each into a variable, then publish those variables -OR- write them to a file you can read.

```
    $Machines = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com' | Select-Object Name

    # generate collection to store data for each outcome
    $ComputerNotRespond = @()
    $ComputerResponse = @()

    foreach ($Machine in $Machines)
    {
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Machine -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Machine -ScriptBlock {
                $Data = Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Wi-Fi*" -DisplayName "Roaming Aggressiveness" | Select-Object Name,DisplayName,DisplayValue,PSComputerName
            }
            $ComputerResponse += $Data
        }
        else
        {
            $ComputerNotRespond += "Computer ${Machine} does not respond"
        }
    }
```

Now you can pubish the outcome of the $ComputerNotRespond to a text file:

```
    $ComputerNotRespond | Out-File C:\tmp\computer_not_respond.txt -Append
```

And you can get the results into CSV to read later:

```
    $ComputerResponse | Export-Csv -Path C:\tmp\computer_response.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'm getting a blank csv file when I run this